# $A$ has 3 shares in a lottery containing 3 prizes and 5 blanks;$B$ has two shares in a lottery containing 2 prizes and 6 blanks

Tags: probability

$A$ has 3 shares in a lottery containing 3 prizes and 5 blanks;$B$ has two shares in a lottery containing 2 prizes and 6 blanks.Compare their chances of success.

Probability of $A$ winning the lottery is $\frac{3}{8}$.

Probability of $B$ winning the lottery is $\frac{2}{8}$.

But these ''shares'',how can i use them in the solution.They are confusing me.
How can i solve this question,i made unfruitful tries for this question.

Thanks.

Comment: Show what you tried.

Comment: i just edit my answer for showing my try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Compare their chances of success" is very vague.

P(A gets k prizes) = $\binom{3}{k}\binom{5}{3-k}/\binom{8}{3}$, k = 0 to 3

P(B gets k prizes) = $\binom{2}{k}\binom{6}{2-k}/\binom{8}{2}$ , k = 0 to 2

Now compare them in whichever way you think the questioner wants !

Answer (score 0):

Look at the probability of them not winning.

On the first draw, A has a 5/8 chance of not winning, if he did not win, he has a 4/7 chance to win on the second draw. On the last draw, assuming he has not won yet he has a 3/6 chance to win. So, A has a (5/8)x(4/7)x(3/6) chance (17.8%) of not winning, or an 82.2% chance of winning.

`1 - ((5/8)*(4/7)*(3/6)) = .822`

Doing the same for B gets you a 46.4% chance of winning.

`1 - ((6/8)*(5/7)) = .464`

Answer (score 0):

probability for A to loss = 9C3 /12C3

probability for A to win  = 1 - 9C3 /12C3  =1 -84/220  =136/220

probability for B to loss = 6C2 /8C2

probability for B to win  = 1 - 6C2 /8C2  =1 -15/28  =13/28

CHANCES RATIO OF A TO B IS (136*28)/(13*220)=  :